# Switch Parent Children relationship in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Using C# and WPF I have a situation where my data is organized hierarchically.
I am using a treeview to represent this (each node is a Class type that containts a Children property that is an ObservableCollection:

- Group_01

  - Object_01

    - Material_01

      - Texture
    - Material_02

      - Texture_02
- Group_02

  - Object_02

    - Material_03

      - Texture_03

I would like to be able to switch the order of the hierarchy, for example be able to create the data starting from the Materials and know all the objects that use that particular material

- Material_02

  - Object_01

    - Group_01
  - Object_02

    - Group_02

What is it the recommended data structure to organize the data? And how I could switch easily between any of these visualizations?